# Merging an unknown number of result sets in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, union, temp-tables

What is the best strategy for merging an unknown number of resultsets into a single, sortable paginated resultset?

Background, I have a fairly complex query that users can build N times and then submit all of those queries at once.  The N queries all return the same formatted result set but have wildly different WHERE clauses.

I could use an SPROC to generate dynamic sql statements based on their input or execute each query seperately and process it in the code, but there's got to be a better way to do it.  Is there an optimal solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the queries all return the same formatted result, you can just union them together and use order by to sort the result

```
select col1, col2, col3 from tablea where ...
 union
select  col1, col2, col3 from tablea where ...
 order by col1, col2
```

If you care about knowing which query returned the result, you would need to add an extra column that indicated the query.

Depending on the size of the N number of queries that are generated, there could also be issues with the size of the total union query.  I ran into issues with JDBC limiting the size of the query when trying to combine many queries this way and wound up doing individual database calls and merging the results in java code.

Comment: Would you recommend just dynamically building the statement since N changes based on how many resultsets the user requests?

Comment: I don't see that you have a choice if the query is based on user input.  It seems like the only way you could do it without a dynamically generated query would be if you could enumerate all the possible combinations ahead of time and then just pick the correct query at runtime.